# Laravel socialite doesn't return user array

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using socialite to login with facebook with my Laravel site.
When I am trying

```
 $user = Socialite::driver($services)->user();
```

Then $user returning an empty array

But if I use `$user = Socialite::driver($services);`

Then `$user` returning huge data but I couldn't see any user-related data

Comment: What is the content of $services ?

Comment: I am passing facebook as parameter in $services